# How to set default page layout

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, page-layout, onet

I have created a site definition, when creating a subsite my layout that I want to use doesn't get set?

How can I set my own default page layout when creating a subiste?

Here is my onet.xml
    [image: img]

Doing like this doesn't change my default publishing page layout

```
<Modules>
<Module Name="MyDef" Url="$Resources:osrvcore,List_Pages_UrlName;" Path="">
  <File Url="default.aspx" >
    <Property Name="Title" Value="$Resources:cmscore,IPPT_HomeWelcomePage_Title;" />
    <Property Name="PublishingPageLayout" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/FSF_Avdelningsplats_Elmia.aspx, $Resources:cmscore,PageLayout_WelcomeLinks_Title;" />
    <Property Name="ContentType" Value="$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_welcomepage_name;" />
  </File>
</Module>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set that in the publishing feature itself in onet.xml, basically in the publishing feature inside you web features, you should do something like this:

```
<WebFeatures>
 <Feature ID='Id for publishing feature'>
   <Properties xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <Property Key="DefaultPageLayout" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs+masterpage/MyPageLayout.aspx"/>
   </Properties>
    </Feature>
    <!-- Other web features..-->    
</WebFeatures>
```

Comment: which is the Id for publishing feature?

Comment: i got this error. The establishment failed. Details: Failed to initialize some website features of the site with the URL : http: //portal.mydev.local/lop Original exception : No parameter less constructor defined for this object .

Comment: This error means you have a problem with your page layout, make sure that you don't have anything outside content place holders, and the ContentPlaceHolders are in the right case, it's different ContentPlaceHolder from contentplaceholder, revise your page layout. It should work

Comment: Hi i have tried with other page layouts that i havent written anything in still got same error

Comment: Did you try to set the page layout manually in the site after creating the page?

Comment: How could i change the page layout for a already created subsite?

Comment: My sub site that i create with my template dont have the propertie page layout, like when i use a built in template

Comment: On the home page for the subsite, edit the page, and from the page tab, you will have "Page Layouts", so change the layout from that section.

Comment: no i dont have it for my subsites using my template?

Comment: when i am creating a subsite with default template built in, my url gets for ex, mysubsite/sites but when creating with my own template its gets only mysubsite?

Comment: Then you are not activating the publishing feature on your site, make sure you activate the publishing feature, add it to your site definition and deploy your page layout.

Comment: But how should i activate it when i then get the error in the top that i wrote before

Comment: Activating publishing feature is different than what you wrote before, you have to include it in your site definition as <Feature .. />, the code you wrote it includes page layout not a feature.

Comment: I have done like u wrote this is my feature <Feature ID='22a9ef51-737b-4ff2-9346-694633fe4416'>

Comment: <Feature ID='22a9ef51-737b-4ff2-9346-694633fe4416'>
          <Properties xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
            <Property Key="DefaultPageLayout" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/FSF_Avdelningsplats_Elmia.aspx"/>

          </Properties>
        </Feature>